# JWT can not be decipher from keys

Tags: java, jwt

Got the following JWT key creation.
However, we wanted to upgrade our io.jsonwebtoken to 0.11.2 and saw that the signWithMethod was deprecated.
Changed the signing to a key, however, the older keys are not compatible with the key deciphering...WHY, HOW?
Can not go to prod if it breaks already issued keys.

```
       private final String secretKeyEncoded = Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(secretKey.getBytes());


       Key key = new SecretKeySpec(secretKeyEncoded.getBytes(), SignatureAlgorithm.HS256.getJcaName());

        final String originalJWT = Jwts.builder()
                .setClaims(claims)
                .setIssuedAt(now)
                .setExpiration(validity)
                .signWith(SignatureAlgorithm.HS256, secretKeyEncoded)
                .compact();

        Jwts.parser().setSigningKey(secretKeyEncoded).parseClaimsJws(originalJWT);//old way
        Jwts.parserBuilder().setSigningKey(secretKeyEncoded).build().parseClaimsJws(originalJWT);
        Jwts.parserBuilder().setSigningKey(new String(key.getEncoded())).build().parseClaimsJws(originalJWT);
        Jwts.parserBuilder().setSigningKey(key).build().parseClaimsJws(originalJWT);//!!!!!! THIS IS NOT WORKING
        final String newJWT = Jwts.builder()
                .setClaims(claims)
                .setIssuedAt(now)
                .setExpiration(validity)
                .signWith(key, SignatureAlgorithm.HS256)
                .compact();

        Jwts.parser().setSigningKey(key).parseClaimsJws(newJWT);//old way depricated
        Jwts.parserBuilder().setSigningKey(secretKeyEncoded.getBytes()).build().parseClaimsJws(newJWT);
        Jwts.parserBuilder().setSigningKey(key).build().parseClaimsJws(newJWT); // THIS ONE WORKS !!!!
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`signWith` overload that takes a `String`](https://github.com/jwtk/jjwt/blob/master/api/src/main/java/io/jsonwebtoken/JwtBuilder.java#L387) requires the string to contain the base64 encoding of the actual key, but the other overloads (including both `Key` and `byte[]`) take the actual key NOT a base64 encoding. This is quite clearly stated; did you not read the javadoc?
This corrected code using base64 for the `String` version and NOT for the `Key` AND `byte[]` versions works correctly for all combinations.

```
static void SO69863437Jjwt (String[] args) throws Exception {
    final String secretKey = "thisisanicelongsecretkey12345678", // BAD IDEA: shouldn't be String
            secretKeyEncoded = Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(secretKey.getBytes());
    final Date now = new Date(), validity = new Date(now.getTime()+86400000);

    Key key = new SecretKeySpec( //WRONG secretKeyEncoded.getBytes(), SignatureAlgorithm.HS256.getJcaName());
            secretKey.getBytes(), SignatureAlgorithm.HS256.getJcaName()); // NOT BASE64!

    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    final String originalJWT = Jwts.builder() //.setClaims(claims)
            .setIssuedAt(now) .setExpiration(validity)
            .signWith(SignatureAlgorithm.HS256, secretKeyEncoded)
            .compact();
    //Jwts.parser().setSigningKey(secretKeyEncoded).parseClaimsJws(originalJWT);//old way
    Jwts.parserBuilder().setSigningKey(secretKeyEncoded).build().parseClaimsJws(originalJWT);
    //ONLY WORKED WITH WRONG Key Jwts.parserBuilder().setSigningKey(new String(key.getEncoded())).build().parseClaimsJws(originalJWT);
    Jwts.parserBuilder().setSigningKey(secretKey.getBytes()).build().parseClaimsJws(originalJWT); //BETTER
    Jwts.parserBuilder().setSigningKey(key).build().parseClaimsJws(originalJWT);// NOW WORKS

    final String newJWT = Jwts.builder() //.setClaims(claims)
            .setIssuedAt(now) .setExpiration(validity)
            .signWith(key, SignatureAlgorithm.HS256)
            .compact();
    //Jwts.parser().setSigningKey(key).parseClaimsJws(newJWT);//old way depricated
    //ONLY WORKED WITH WRONG Key Jwts.parserBuilder().setSigningKey(secretKeyEncoded.getBytes()).build().parseClaimsJws(newJWT);
    Jwts.parserBuilder().setSigningKey(secretKey.getBytes()).build().parseClaimsJws(newJWT); //BETTER
    Jwts.parserBuilder().setSigningKey(secretKeyEncoded).build().parseClaimsJws(newJWT); // FIXED
    Jwts.parserBuilder().setSigningKey(key).build().parseClaimsJws(newJWT); // THIS ONE WORKS !!!!
    
    System.out.println ("done");
}
```

Note however that using the bytes of an arbitrary Java `String` as a cryptographic key is a bad idea (hence my comment). It limits the entropy making your system less secure, especially if used with human-meaningful content (like my example!) which isn't secure at all, plus `getBytes()` is locale-dependent so it may cause everything to fail if used across multiple systems or environments -- although the latter issue may be less significant for HMAC signatures because those generally can only be used securely on a single system.

And there's no deciphering (or ciphering) here at all, only signature generation and verification.